# VB.Net / Winform - draw a line?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using visual studio 2010 and vb.net.
On my form I have an Group Box that I use to visually segment various controls on the form. 
My question is how can I add a horizontal line that looks the same as the border lines of the Group Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan is a heckofalot closer then he might have thought.  Add a GroupBox, set the Text property to an empty string, change the Size property to make the Height equal to 2.  Presto, horizontal carved battle-ship gray line like seen on many dialogs.

Comment: I considered that (but wasn't at my dev machine to try it). Personally, I'm a little nervous doing stuff like that because I'm not 100% convinced it will look the same on all computers and future versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to use a group box, as this is more standard.

If you need something custom, use write your own Paint handler to paint whatever you need.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write Group Box!

Comment: bochur1: What about a group box? Just put one on your form if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how an option box would visually segment controls, but have a look at the **LineShape** control in the Visual Basic PowerPacks (from Microsoft).

(Google "Visual Basic PowerPacks", download it from MS, then install it.)